# After a new install of ubuntu 14

Tags: compiz, updates, startup

I have a HP dc5800 with VMWare Workstation. New Ubuntu installation worked perfect.

I cancelled the language selection because I had no internet connection to the virtual machine.

Ubuntu asked me to do a 251 updates. After the restart from those updates Ubuntu hangs on *Battery check OK*.

With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `startx` I got into the system.

The second problem I found was that the system asked me for a password when I type `startx`.

Because the password is not accepted I get a second option to log on, this time with a login name field first. I choose administrator (did I choose did with setup, or is it default like in windows) and type my password. Directly I am in and type `startx` again.
I am asking myself what was the user accound for the first logon try(it is not saying).

With the full language support I get the same problem. Asking me for a password without telling me which user it wants.

After several tries the system still complains about being incomplete, but I see that the English language is installed(the one I wanted).

Then I got an empty desktop with no options. I have to crash the virtual machine to get somewhere.

Extra:

While updating it told me that a part was ended unexpected (`compiz`), but not enough memory to send a report to the developers.

Hope somebody has an idea.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @fossfreedom It seems to be a self Q&A. I've moved the answer part to an answer. **Michael**: I've edited this for clarity, but if you can improve it further, that would help; it's not obvious *what* the problem is that you had. The answer also doesn't seem to reveal *what* advice you followed to solve the problem. (And there's no Ubuntu 14; there isn't even a release of Ubuntu whose version number *starts* with 14.) Unless some of these problems are improved and it's clear at least what the *solution* was, this question may be closed. (If it is, it can still be improved and reopened, though.)

Answer (score 0):

*The OP reported solving the problem. He wrote:*

The first step of my solution was in:

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
Not the first solution but the second where I had to use the T. Doing the same in graphical mode, I saw that it asked for a password. Then it went on. Then did the sudo reboot again.

After the reboot I end up in an empty black screen with no prompt. I can typ but no command is accept(there is local echo).(i see that i am in tty7 but no prompt).
I went to tty1, logged in, went to startx and got again an empty desktop on tty7 and tty8. So I went to tty2. 
ren the sudo apt-get install pastebinit && pastebinit /var/log/Xorg.0.log 
On advise used the sudo apt-get autoremove.
then sudo reboot.

Problem was solved. I got my desktop back. Still not sure which password the system wanted.